# If statement to go through number line

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to animate a model about a center point, and I want it to swing back and forth (it's a leg). I'm unsure about my if conditions. Particularly when it's trying to reduce the angle. What I've got now, it seems to:

1. Increase angle until > 46
2. Go in the last if statement, minus 0.1 from angle, (makes it < 46)
3. Now instead of continuing to go in the last if statement until angle = 0, it goes back to second if function.

I want it keep on decreasing until 0, then increase again. (Please note that this whole block of code is in a for loop when it's called).

P/s: CenterPointVec[] is a vector containing x, y and z axis values.

```
void vertex::AnimatePart()
{
    static float angle = 0;
    bool goback = false;

         if(angle == 0)
{
    glTranslatef(CenterPointVec[0], CenterPointVec[1], CenterPointVec[2]);
    glRotatef(angle, 1,0,0);
    glTranslatef(-CenterPointVec[0], -CenterPointVec[1], -CenterPointVec[2]);

    angle += 0.1;
    goback = false;
}

if(angle < 46 && goback == false)
{
    glTranslatef(CenterPointVec[0], CenterPointVec[1], CenterPointVec[2]);
    glRotatef(angle, 1,0,0);
    glTranslatef(-CenterPointVec[0], -CenterPointVec[1], -CenterPointVec[2]);

    angle += 0.1;

    if(angle > 46)
    {
        goback = true;
        cout << "Angle : " << angle << endl;
        cout << "Go back? " << goback << endl;
    }

}

if(angle > 0 && goback == true)
{
    glTranslatef(CenterPointVec[0], CenterPointVec[1], CenterPointVec[2]);
    glRotatef(angle, 1,0,0);
    glTranslatef(-CenterPointVec[0], -CenterPointVec[1], -CenterPointVec[2]);

    angle -= 0.1;

    if(angle <= 0)
        {
            goback = false;
            cout << "Angle : " << angle << endl;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: the problem seems not to be related to the translations and rotations. Why dont you remove all these function calls and replace them with some `cout`s. Then you will see what is going on.

Comment: the first block (`if (angle==0)...` is not needed. This is already covered by the second block (`if (angle<46)...`)

Comment: What do you mean with "it goes back to second if function." ? Is it possible that it does not "go back", but it continues with the next iteration of the outer loop (the one that you mention but not show here)?

Comment: I think the problem is your conditions. The last time then angle is incremented it gets incremented to 46. Thus both `angle<46` and `angle>46` are `false` and `goback` is never set to `true`

Comment: When you've decremented `angle` to less than 46 and then call the function again, you start off with `bool goback = false;`, i.e. `angle < 46 && goback == false`.

Comment: @tobi303 I understand, but what I wanted to achieve with this code was to start from let's say `int i = 0`, then I will increase the i value only if `i < 46`. However, when `i > 46`, I want the i to be decreased back one by one (or in this case, 0.1) until it reaches 0 and increases again.

Comment: yes, but inbetween `angle < 46` and `angle >46` there is the case where `angle==46` and you do not take this into account. The block inside `if (angle<46){...angle+=0.1;if (angle>46){ this }` is never executed.

Comment: Already your description is flawed: If you increase only if `i<46` it will never be `i>46`